# The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListGroup' requires a key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Not sure what happened but I am getting the following error while attempting to pull up any view in my web app. The code is auto generated by visual studio and I am not getting any errors before building. Using ASP.Net MVC 6, EF7.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListGroup' requires a key to be defined.

Here is the line the code is erroring out on.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var schoolContext = _context.Schools
                                .Include(s => s.District)
                                .Include(s => s.Location)
                                .Include(s => s.Tier);
    return View(schoolContext.ToList());
}
```

After some searching I can't figure out exactly what I need to fix. This was working at one point. Not sure what changed.

The view does have a defenition

```
@model IEnumerable<School>
```

As requested here is the School model

```
public class School
{
    //Original Fields
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Date Added")]
    public DateTime SchoolDateAdded { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Update")]
    public DateTime SchoolLastUpdate { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name="Updated By")]
    public string SchoolUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    //Referance Fields
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DistrictList { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
    public int TierId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TierList { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public District District { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Tier Tier { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Taking a wild guess, but possibly one of your entities doesn't have a PK defined?

Comment: Define `@model` type in your view first.

Comment: I added that i do define the model in the view and every database table has a id field.

Comment: Just for the shiggles, try removing your `Includes()` and see what happens.

Comment: removing includes still throws the same error only on the return statement not the definition statement

Comment: Can we see your `School` model?

Comment: Added the school model to the post

Comment: Pretty sure `SchoolId` needs the `[Key]` attribute. This is just a guess though. My Experience in EF7 is limited so for all I know this is taken care of behind the scenes.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not correct it do I need to re-generate and update the database?

Comment: Yes the database will need to reflect your model.

Comment: I just verified all the ID fields are already set as PK in the database and model still throwing the error.

Comment: These `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`s should *not* be part of your EF model. Remember the *single responsibility* principle. Keep any UI framework away from your DAL implementation. Use a view model representing a `School`.

Comment: Thank you as I read this I realized thats the last thing I added I was trying to follow the details of the error I am receiving on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820483/dropdownlists-not-populating-with-data-from-3-separate-reference-tables which I still haven't resolved.

Comment: If you could post this as an answer I will mark as correct thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`s should *not* be part of your EF model. Remember the *single responsibility principle*. Keep any UI framework away from your DAL implementation. Use a view model representing a `School`.

As for the error, from EF's point of view, `School` has a 1-n association with `SelectListItem`, so it tries to make it part of its mapping schema. But each mapped type needs a primary key, which of course isn't mapped, and EF can't infer any.

A quick, but dirty, fix would be to exclude the properties from being mapped by the [`[NotMapped]` attribute](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/included-properties.html), but a better segregation of your code is the real remedy.